# Region of interest of YV12 matrix

Tags: android, opencv, matrix, colors, yuv

This question is a crosspost from http://answers.opencv.org/question/22242/region-of-interest-of-yv12-matrix/ (I did not received an answer so far).

I have the following OpenCV matrix in YV12 colorspace (stored as 1-channel image). It's filled with data which came from Android camera preview.

```
mYuv  = new Mat(480 + (480/2), 640, CvType.CV_8UC1);
```

Is it possible to extract some sub-region of this image (first step) and convert it to RGB colorspace subsequently (second step)? I would like to extract region first in order to keep good performance when converting. To say, I want to extract the following rect:

```
x: 150
y: 50
width: 60
height: 60
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use **submat**

```
roi = mYuv.submat(new Rect(x,y,width,height));
```

And then **Imgproc.cvtColor** with the correct code.
I have no way of checking it right now, but I would try:

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(roi, destination, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV2RGB_YV12);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, but I've already tried to pass my ROI to a `Mat` copy constructor and got OpenCV assert exception. This method obviously won't work because YUV is stored in 1-channel image hence there should be some kind of pre-processing.